# Sample paths of a diffusion are almost surely non-constant?

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider a scalar diffusion $X=(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ given by

$\mathrm{d}X_t = b(t,X_t)\mathrm{d}t + \sigma(t,X_t)\mathrm{d}B_t, \quad X_0 = \xi$

for sufficiently regular coefficients $b$ and $\sigma$ and some initial state $\xi$.

Is there a result which guarantees that for every closed interval $I\subset[0,\infty)$ of positive measure, the sample paths of $(X_t)_{t\in I}$ are almost surely non-constant?

Comment: Perhaps it is easiest to consider the Wiener process first. It is nowhere differentiable a.s. (see e.g. https://www.math.wisc.edu/~roch/grad-prob/gradprob-notes27.pdf). Constant sample path would seem to contradict this.